# Custom LaTeX template for bookdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown

I've recently upgraded my computer with new OS, new version of R (4.0) and consequently all packages. When trying to compile a [bookdown](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown) document to pdf that used to work, I now get the error message

> LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.

If I look at the tex file that is generated then I see that the following packages are added by the `bookdown` package by default to the file.

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xcolor}
```

I have a bunch of other LaTeX-packages that are loaded earlier via the `_output.yml` file and the line `in_header: latex/preamble.tex` and I'm guessing that the clash is due to one of those. If I manually remove the last line containing `\usepackage{xcolor}` then everything compiles nicely.

But how do I modify the custom template that is used to add these default packages listed above?  I checked the templates listed by pandoc but none of those seem to add these packages.

Following the information in the [bookdown book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-template.html) it is possible to add a custom template, but the [default LaTeX template from pandoc](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/tree/master/data/templates) doesn't include those package either, so where do they come from?

Where can I find the default template that includes these extra packages for me? Or can I perhaps force `xcolor` to work by including a `\PassOptionsToPackage{something}{xcolor}` earlier in my LaTeX preamble?

(I am using the `bookdown::tufte_book2` format but I haven't found the packages when hunting through the templates in the `tufte` package)

Comment: maybe bookdown is using an old pandoc version with associated template? not sure...

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83102

Answer (score 1):

Since [bookdown 0.4](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/releases/tag/v0.4) you can use a global option `bookdown.post.latex` to post-process the LaTeX output. So I added the following code in a chunk (with `echo=FALSE`) to `index.Rmd`:

```
options(bookdown.post.latex = function(x) {
  # x is the content of the LaTeX output file
  c('\\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}',x)    
})
```

In my `preamble.tex` I had

```
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}
```

And the LaTeX table I used was:

```
\rowcolors{3}{green!80!yellow!50}{green!70!yellow!40}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|  }
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Country List} \\
\hline
Country Name or Area Name& ISO ALPHA 2 Code &ISO ALPHA 3 \\
\hline
American Samoa & AS & ASM \\
Andorra & AD & AND   \\
Angola & AO & AGO \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```